# Using a sliding window in stream analytics causes a type conversion error (bigint somehow becomes a double)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

So I'm trying to run the following query in stream analytics:

```
WITH
InputData AS(
    SELECT 
        tags.[tag0] AS 'shift',
        tags.[tag1] AS 'Good Count',
        tags.[tag2] AS 'Bad Count'
    FROM 
        [Kepware]
),

Transform1 AS(
    SELECT
        shift,
        CASE
            WHEN [Good Count] - (LAG([Good Count], 1, [Good Count]) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(day, 1))) < 0 THEN [Good Count] + 1
            ELSE [Good Count] - (LAG([Good Count], 1, [Good Count]) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(day, 1)))
        END AS [Good Diff],
        CASE
            WHEN [Bad Count] - (LAG([Bad Count], 1, [Bad Count]) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(day, 1))) < 0 THEN [Bad Count] + 1
            ELSE [Bad Count] - (LAG([Bad Count], 1, [Bad Count]) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(day, 1)))
        END AS [Bad Diff]
    FROM
        [InputData]
)

SELECT
    SUM([Good Diff]) AS [Shift Good Count]
INTO
    [LiveTableTest]
FROM
    [Transform1]
WHERE 
    shift = 1
GROUP BY
    SlidingWindow(hour,8)
```

When I run the test query it shows the correct result in the test results tab. The SQL table schema (preview) tab shows that the result is a bigint just like the table column, yet I get this error and nothing gets written to the table.

> "[SQL Server Azure instance 'mysqlserverxxxxx.database.windows.net',
> table [Database].[Live Table Test]] Cannot write 4 events to SQL
> Database output at LiveTableTest. Detailed Error:  - Conversion of
> property 'Shift Good Count' of type 'System.Double' to table
> column 'Shift Good Count' of type 'System.Int64' is not
> supported.\r\n"

When I go into the database I can see the column I'm trying to fill is a bigint so I'm not sure what is happening here. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I changed the SQL column to float and now the output is as expected but I'm not sure why the change to double/float occurs when the output still looks like an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this for that I followed below procedure.
I have given output through raspberry pi azure online simulator and created IOT hub and added one device for that.

[image]

After that I copied the connection string of that device pasted in raspberry pi azure online simulator to get the input messages.

**Input:**

[image]

I run the code which is given above.
[image]

When I enter double data type I also got the same error. instead of that I used float it is working fine.

**Output when float is used:**
[image]

Why because ***double is not supported datatype in stream analytics***. For more information regarding datatypes, go through this [Data Types (Azure Stream Analytics) - Stream Analytics Query | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/data-types-azure-stream-analytics)

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not sure this solution helps. My input is only bigints and floats. There are no doubles in my input. The transformation appears to be somehow causing a conversion to double despite what you say about stream analytics not allowing doubles.